# parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' when appendChild(img)

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm currently working on a side project, and working with DOM manipulation.

Below, I created a function `addImage`. When the browser calls this function, it returns the following error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```
function addImage(data) {
    let imageElement = new Image();
    imageElement.src = data;
    console.log(imageElement);
    let imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
    imageContainer.appendChild('imageElement');
}

imageElement = `<img src="https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/t51.2885-19/11193017_906607852718693_821675199_a.jpg">`
```

I looked at other questions with this typeError. In those examples, string was being added to a div element.

Comment: Just to clarify, when the console returns the imageElement, it shows the img element w/ the src attribute (URL is attached)

Comment: `imageContainer.appendChild(imageElement);`

Comment: `appendChild()` accepts node as an argument You are giving it string. Change this `.appendChild(imageElement)`

Comment: This line: `imageContainer.appendChild("imageElement")`. imageElement is a node that you just created 4 lines above, yet here you are passing it in as a string into a function which requires a Node object. Change it to `imageContainer.appendChild(imageElement)`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I thought the appendChild method worked like getElementById.

Comment: errors are not meant to be copy & pasted onto stack overflow but are rather good hints on the things that are wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You used [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to append `imageElement` to the `imageContainer`, you should pass an element (*node*) to the `appendChild()`, but you passed `string`, that's the reason of the error.

So, change

```
imageContainer.appendChild('imageElement');
```

To

```
imageContainer.appendChild(imageElement);
```

And you are good to go.

[Working example](https://codepen.io/digitalify/pen/GBGpZP)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was returning the element from a function that had not yet completed creating it (I assume it was because I was also setting the src in the function).  When I set `await` on the call to create the img, the failure resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the ' '(single quatation) from imageElement, else it will treat as a string, that leads this error.

> imageContainer.appendChild(**imageElement**);

```
function addImage(data) {
    let imageElement = new Image();
    imageElement.src = data;
    console.log(imageElement);
    let imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
    imageContainer.appendChild(imageElement);
}

imageElement = `<img src="https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/t51.2885-19/11193017_906607852718693_821675199_a.jpg">`
```